# How to return a filled select when editing the form with Angular?

Tags: angular, spring-boot, angular-material

To make a reservation it is necessary to fill in some fields, among them there is a select field that lists the customers already registered.
When registering a customer, the select field lists the names correctly and saves successfully, but
when I edit this reservation, I need this field already selected with the name of the current customer, I tried the following way but nothing is showing.

Reservation.component.ts

```
customers$: Observable<Customer[]>;

form!: FormGroup;

constructor(private customerService:CustomerService) {
  this.customers$ = this.customerService.list();
}

ngOnInit(): void {
    const reservation: Reservation = this.route.snapshot.data['reservation'];
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      id: [reservation.id],
      customer: [reservation.customer.name, Validators.required],
      professional: [reservation.professional.name, Validators.required],
      reservationDate: [reservation.reservationDate, Validators.required],
      reservationHour: [reservation.reservationHour, Validators.required],
      description: [reservation.description]
    });
  }
```

Reservation.component.html

```
<mat-form-field class="full-width">
   <mat-label>Customer</mat-label>
      <mat-select formControlName="customer">
         <div *ngIf="customers$ | async as customers">
            <mat-option
              *ngFor="let customer of customers"
              [value]="customer"
              >
              {{ customer.nome }}
           </mat-option>
         </div>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```